# Getting python to open a window

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

I want to write a program in Python but I cant find any help on where to start.

All I want to do first is make Python open a simple window when I run the program. I want it to be green and about 500 pixels square. How would I do this?

Comment: You want the window to be green or the content?

Comment: You need to pick a windowing library. Python comes with `Tkinter`, and `turtle` (which is based on it); there are others like GObject and PySide (see [Other Graphical User Interface Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/othergui.html#other-gui-packages) in the docs). Or you can use a lower-level library like PyGame (which doesn't handle widgets, just plain windows that you have to draw on manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html), a builtin Python module made for drawing.

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.bgcolor('green')
```

First you initialize the screen using [`turtle.Screen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.Screen). Then you use [`screen.setup()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.setup) and pass in the screen size you want. Lastly, you use [`screen.bgcolor()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgcolor) to change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tkinter`

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="green")   

        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.title("Window")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```